# 3D manipulator to middle of selection

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, 3d-manipulator

How do I set the 3D manipulator to the middle of my selection?
I am new to Blender and have no idea how it is done. In a tutorial I was looking at, it happens automatically when you do the selection, but in my 2.76b it does not.
I found how the center point of the whole object can be set to the middle of geometry but I do not mean that.
[image: model in edit mode with piece selected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to press <kbd>,</kbd> that is a comma. That will change the *[Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html#pivot-point)* to *Bounding Box Center*.
[image: Pivot Point dialog]
Both *Median Point* and *Bounding Box Center* will place the 3D manipulator in the center of your selection.

Comment: Thanks! Easy trick but for newbie not so self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

Change the pivot point to "Median Point".

You can change the pivot point from here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Pivot point was what I was looking. David gave same kind of answer and I chose it right one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what your question is. Before being edited to "3d manipulator", the first line of your question asked about changing the "Origin point". The origin point is the point at which Blender considers your object to be located, and is indicated for any given object by an orange dot. In the case of your mug, it appears to be in the center of the bowl of the mug, and it can be moved to various locations by using the menu activated by the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>ALT</kbd> - <kbd>SHFT</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd>. Another way to change the relationship between the origin point and the mesh is to go to edit mode, select all of the vertices, and move the vertices relative to the origin point.

If, on the other hand, you mean (as your question was edited), you mean the 3D manipulator widget (the red blue and green devices used in transforming, rotating, and scaling) this is always located at the location designated by the pivot point.

If, on the *other* other hand, you mean the 3D cursor (the red and white circle with crosshairs), this can be easily relocated by placing the mouse pointer at the location in the scene where you want the widget to be located, and left-clicking with the mouse. Alternatively, the location of the 3d cursor can be precisely located by using the panel in the tool shelf (activated by pressing the <kbd>N</kbd> key if it is not visible in the viewport window); simply type the desired location co-ordinates in the boxes in the "3D cursor" panel. Pressing the key combination <kbd>SHFT</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd> activates a menu which allows the 3D cursor to be snapped to various locations relative to the scene, or allows the selected elements of the geometry of the scene to be snapped to various locations relative to the 3D cursor.

Comment: Thanks for response. What I meant by my question, was answered and it was not very hard trick to do :)