# How to use blender to create a grid cylinder?

Tags: mesh, objects

[image: dense mesh cylinder]

I’m new to Blender, but pretty experienced with other 3D software. 
I need to create a mesh cylinder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of   procedural ways to create the cylinder and have its topology consisting of even quads is array a plane to create big plane and bend it afterwards.

1. Add a plane, rotate it so it's oriented up (along Z axis). Put its origin point in the corner (snap 3D cursor to selection when that vertex is selected and in Object mode use *Origin To 3D Cursor*).
2. Start adding modifiers, first will be [Array](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html). Set it to array along Z axis (if using default *Relative Offset* set value of 1 to the Z axis in the modifier options). Set number of iterations so that the height of final result is as height of desired cylinder.
3. Add another Array modifier and set this one to array along horizontal axes (in case of screenshot X). Set number of iterations to number of edges of cylinder.
4. Add [Simple Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html) modifier. Set it to *Bend* mode, then enter value for *Angle* to 360 degrees.

[image]

The modifier stack in this case is

[image]

Otherwise you can add a cylinder, enter Edit mode and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to add loopcuts along its edges. This will be destructive change to geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the other answers seem like overkill for making a simple cylinder.

You do know there is a built in cylinder primitive? OK thought so.

So add a cylinder (three easy ways to do that) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Cylinder*, from the tool shelf the *Create* tab *Cylinder* button, or from the 3D view header  *Add* > *Mesh* > *Cylinder*.

***WAIT*** before you do anything else you need to change the settings. Once blender has moved on to something else (say set it to smooth shading, or add a material) the settings are locked in stone. Only way to change it is to delete and add anew.

So in the bottom half of the tool shelf (called the "operator history") you can change the settings for the cylinder. You can get to these same settings by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.
The two settings you should change are the *Vertices* set that to 64, and the *Cap Fill Type* you want that to be set to "*Nothing.*"

[image: unedited cylinder]
Already you are about half way there.

In edit mode, start by selecting the top edge loop (just <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on it to select the whole thing.) With that selected, press <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>0</kbd>. That will extrude new geometry, and scale that geometry to 0 (assuming you have the [Pivot Point](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46185/2217) set to *Median Point*).

[image: extruded a top for the cylinder]

Add some loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to the newly created top faces. Use the <kbd>MMW [image: MMW]</kbd> and scroll up to increase the number of edges you will be adding. After you have the pink guide lines in the correct spot and the number you want, <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm that then <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> to cancel the edge slide, because you want the new edges centered.

[image: loop cuts added to the top]

Exact same process to add the loop cuts to the side of the cylinder.

Now you *could* do the bottom too, but why bother? That would just be duplicating work, throw a [mirror modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) on and let blender use the top you already did.

[image: a nice dense mesh cylinder]
If I may say, that's a good looking picture of a cylinder in edit mode.

Yes ok you all can have a gif. Do you all really need an animated gif showing how to add loop cuts to a cylinder?
[image: animated gif showing the process described in this answer. took me longer then is should have to make]

Answer (score 1):

With a rather elaborate modifier stack this can be done procedurally either from the default cube, or a single vertex. For a single vertex rather than a cube, you may omit the first two steps.

[image]

The modifier stack expanded in the below images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Explanation *(If beginning with a single vertex and not the default cube, omit the first two steps.)*:

1. [Displace Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier) to shrink the cube
2. [Weld Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/weld.html#weld-modifier) to merge the vertices to a single vertex.
3. [Screw Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html#screw-modifier) on `X` for width of cylinder
4. A second screw on `z` 360 degrees to create a filled circle
5. [Solidify Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) to extrude and create the cylinder.
6. [Edge Split](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html#edge-split-modifier) to create hard edges on the object
7. [Decimate Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html#decimate-modifier) to slightly reduce the geometry at this stage.
8. [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) set to *simple* to add the beginning of the grid
9. [Bevel Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#bevel-modifier) continues to add detail of the grid
10. A second [Weld Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/weld.html#weld-modifier) to remove loose geometry at this point
11. [Remesh Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html#remesh-modifier) set to *voxel* finish the grid density

Answer (score -1):

Another way. I'm new to Blender so I assume it is a none procedural way..

1. Create a circle.
2. Enter Edit mode and Extract + Escape.
3. Scale the newly extracted vertices to 0.
4. Select complete mesh and remove doubles.
5. Deselect mesh and circle select then center of the circle to select all spokes.
6. Subdivide, in the subdivide menu select the number of Cuts.
7. Extact mesh in Z direction a short distance.
8. Tab out to Object mode and use the Array modifier in Z-direction. Select desired Count.
9. Apply modifier and voila you have a mesh in analogue with you picture.