# I want to move vertices in an accurate way but the 3D Manipulator is missing

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I want to move vertices in an accurate way but the [3D Manipulator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/manipulators.html) is missing? How can I reveal that?

[image]

It's already enabled:

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46183/3d-manipulator-to-middle-of-selection

Comment: it looks like your Pivot Point is on 3D Cursor (button with a circle on the bottom of your picture), choose Median Point for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you set the 3d cursor as your pivot point.

I can't see the 3d Cursor is not to be see in your view. The 3d manipulator is in the same place as the 3d cursor, therefore is it offscreen as well.

Change the pivot point to any other setting (like median point) to the 3D Cursor show at the current selection.